# Using Zend_Acl with Redirect/Forward

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-acl

In my controller I have some actions with redirects to another actions. For example:

```
public function editAction()
{
    $this->_forward('add');
}
```

I'd like to allow user only access the `editAction`, but I need give him access to `addAction` too. There is any way to give him only access to `editAction` even if it redirects to `addAction`?

Thank you.

Comment: Any success with it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this kind of control over your application is ingecting a plugin on yout bootstrap so  the action is verified before it reaches the controller.

You need to write a plugin that extends **Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract** and override the **preDispatch** function, which has as a parameter a request object. From the request you can get controller name and action name and that's when you validate it from you ACL rules and redirect the user  wherever you want.

```
if($request->getControllerName() == 'MyController' &&
   $request->getActionName() == 'edit'){
  if(!$myAcl->isAllowed('edit')){
    $request->setActionName('add');
  }
}
```

This way you don't have to put a lot of rules on your controllers and keep safe on a plugin.
Hope it helps.